# What happens if a startup idea fails? How do the bank recover money?

Tags: entrepreneurship

Suppose I take a loan with the intention of using it to develop certain products. It so happens that I have used up all the money on R&D to conclude that the product is not good or feasible. As a result I would have no business earning to repay the load. In this case, how does the bank recovers the money.

Comment: There is nothing unclear about this question.

Comment: @Edwin So what? It’s still 100% off-topic. The bottom line is it *should* be closed.

Comment: @nobody So the closer(s) aren't closing for the reasons they are stating?  Well, then.  That is a good indicator that the job isn't being done well, and a smaller indicator that motivation can be rewritten after-the-fact.  Even if I agree that by a different path, the outcome would be the same for this forum, this is a strong indicator that closer(s) aren't closing properly (which opens questions if they are closing properly elsewhere).

Comment: The bank will collect on the collateral that you put up for the loan when you default. You will still be responsible to pay back the loan unless you file for bankruptcy. Depending on the facts even that might not be enough

Comment: Most likely they will go after whatever assets the company has they can liquidate. This should all be specified in the contract you signed when you took the loan. Make sure you read and understand the terms of the loan before you sign.

Answer (score 11):

Banks would not normally lend money to a startup with no track record unless they had a personal guarantee from the founders and most likely also pledged collateral like the founder's or founder's friends and family's houses.

Normally startups are funded by stock purchase by the founder's friends, families (and fools, as the saying goes) angel investors, doctors and dentists etc. People who buy shares get nothing, or a penny on the dollar, if the company fails.

Getting to some success, the company might attract professional venture capital or funds from industrial partners.

Comment: As an example of personal guarantees, many a startup is funded by personal credit cards which have to be paid off by the founder even if the business goes under.

Comment: _"Normally startups are funded by stock purchase by the founder's friends, families (and fools, as the saying goes) angel investors,"_ ..and companies managing venture capital fonds if the start-up passes seed & series A phase.

Answer (score 5):

Most banks won't give you a loan without some collateral (usually a non-movable asset like your house or precious metals like gold). If you are unable to repay your loan you usually end up forfeiting the collateral.

If you are lucky enough to find a bank that will give you a loan for a startup, without any collateral, the bank can still go after you legally to get back the money you borrowed. If the bank asked a guarantor to back the loan, they'll go after them too.

Most startups don't get their money from banks as the banks consider such loans risky. Instead, startups try to secure funding from other investors who do not mind investing in risky ventures. Here is a brief and simple guide on how businesses raise funds when they start and as they grow - [Origin of a Business](https://zerodha.com/varsity/chapter/the-ipo-markets-part-1/).

Comment: No, If the bank lent the money to *a corporation* and there was no personal guarantee than it is incorrect that the bank can go after the founders, assuming there has been no fraud or other activity that lets them go through the corporate veil.. The company and the founders are not the same "person".

Comment: @George - A bank does not give a corporation money, they give the person that own the corporation the money. A bank absolutely will not just give money out without some sort of guarantee that the money will be paid back. **That fact isn’t up for debate.**

Comment: Banks lend money to corporations all the time without personal guarantees as long as the company has a track record of profitability and stability. Of course they do not do this for a raw startup with the possible exception of lending against receivables from blue chip clients. What my comment above said is *if* a bank lent to a company with no personal guarantees then there would be no recourse to individuals. I agree that this is very very unlikely in the case of a startup.

Comment: I would suggest rewording that to "bank lend money to corporations all the time without personal guarantees as long as the corporation has sufficient assets for collateral". A corporation that has a history of profitability and stability may still need the owner's personal guarantee. A friend of mine with a long history of profit is still having to put up a personal guarantee.

Comment: @Donald  "A bank absolutely will not just give money out without some sort of guarantee that the money will be paid back. That fact isn’t up for debate."  It's not a fact, have you never heard of unsecured borrowing???!